# Update a child component from another screen in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I tried following a tutorial for React.js but got undefined is not a object error, I do have two different screens with separate classes, first one is dashboard when user select some ingredients, then I send this list to the second screen `Search.js` everything is working fine but no way to update results showing on that screen because I call the api inside componentDidMount, I tried didUpdate not changing anything!

So the code in my parent screen is like that:

```
  switcher() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    navigate('Select', {passedData:this.state.selectedIngredients});
    this.refs.search.apicall()
  }
```

Then on the other screen I got this function:

```
  apicall() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const passedData = navigation.getParam('passedData', 'default value'); 
    let selectedIngredients = passedData;

      fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
          this.setState({
            data: responseJson.results,
            loading: false,
          });
        }) 
  }


    componentDidMount() { 
      this.apicall()
      };
```

The error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating this.refs.search.apicall)

My goal is to remove that componentDidUpdate and create a function to refresh or update the results showing on the `Search.js` screen. Also the ability to handle (run) function from different classes. Can someone please help with that?

Comment: it's not clear what you're doing, do you have a ref called apicall? I think you're using the concept of refs wrong - you should read about them in the documentation

Comment: apicall is a function outside the class i'm trying to call it from. Can you tell me how to use this ref correctly? my main goal is to execute apicall onClick

Comment: so why are you trying to run the following line: `this.refs.search.apicall()`? what are you thinking that's going to do?

Comment: well I imported search.js so it supposed to look for child class named search and then look for a function called apicall and execute it. From the docs this.refs[CHILD_REF].functionName

Comment: before you can use a ref, you have to register it. like the example here for 'creating refs': https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs - however, that's not the right way to use react. I could be more helpful if you post a little more of your code